# Como generar que este template de un pdf creado por Django llegue al correo

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, meta-tags

Hola estoy intentando que este pdf generado por Django llegue al correo de el cliente lo intente en el content de la etiqueta meta asignando la url=mailto:correo@mail.com pero no llega

este es el codigo del generador de pdf

```
    def render_create_proyecto_to_pdf(data_render):
        template_path = 'proyecto_add.html'
        html = render_to_string(template_path, data_render)
        result = BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result)
        if not pdf.err:
            return result.getvalue()
        return None
```

y esta es la contendio de el template

No se si se pueda vincular un form y de alli enviarlo al correo

```
    {% load static %}
    {% load index %}
    {% load i18n %}
    <html>
      <head>
          <title></title>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8; url=mailto:correo@mail.com">
      </head>
      <body>
        {% language 'es' %}
        <table >
          <tr style="height:50px;">
            <th>
              <img class="logo" align="left" src="{% static 'logo.png' %}">
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: {{ tamaño_letra }}%; vertical-align:bottom; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 0;">
              <h4 style="margin:0; font-weight:bold">COTIZACIÓN</h4>
              <h4 style="margin:0;font-weight:lighter">{{ Folio }}</h4>
              {% now "d" as day %}
              {% now "F" as month %}
              {% now "Y" as year %}
              <h4 style="margin:0;font-weight:lighter">
                {{ proyecto.ComunaID.ProvinciaID.Name }}, {{ day }} de {{ month }} de {{ year }}
              </h4>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div>
          <p style="margin:0; font-weight:bold"> Señor(a) </p>
          <p style="margin:0; font-weight:bold"> {{ cliente }} </p>
          <p style="text-decoration:underline;margin:0"> Presente</p>
          <p style="margin-top:2px;"> Estimado(a) cliente:</p>
          <p style="margin-top:1px;">
              De acuerdo a lo solicitado, nos es muy grato cotizar por los inmuebles que se indican, correspondientes al proyecto
              <strong> {{ proyecto.Name }},</strong>
              ubicado en {{ proyecto.Address }}, comuna de {{ proyecto.ComunaID.Name}}, provincia de {{ proyecto.ComunaID.ProvinciaID.Name }}:
          </p>
        </div>
        <h2 style="font-size: 80%; margin-bottom:0">
            <strong>
                1. <span style="text-decoration:underline">INMUEBLES</span>
            </strong>
        </h2>
        <table>
          {% for cotizacion_inmueble in inmuebles_a_cotizar %}
            Contenido
        </table>    
        {% endlanguage %}
      </body>
    </html>
```

el pdf se imprime correctamente pero no es enviado al cliente por correo

Comment: Que libreria de envio de correo estas usando?

Answer (score 1):

***Envio de correos con Gmail.***

**CONFIGURACIÓN.**
Lo primero que debemos hacer es configurar nuestro proyecto; para ellos modificaremos el archivo **settings.py** agregando 5 nuevas constantes.

Como estaremos trabajando con un servidor de correos externo, yo les recomiendo almacenar sus credenciales (user y password) en variables de entorno.

Una librería que me gusta recomendar para trabajar con variables de entorno es decouple. En mi caso haré uso de ella.

```
from decouple import config

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('USER_MAIL')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('USER_MAIL_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Para utilizar gmail como servidor de corres es necesario *permitir el acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras*.

Bien, una vez tengamos las configuraciones el siguiente paso es definir una función la cuales nos permita enviar los correos.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def send_user_mail(user):
    subject = 'Titulo del correo'
    template = get_template('templates/mi_template_correo.html')

    content = template.render({
        'user': user,
    })

    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, #Titulo
                                    ''",
                                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, #Remitente
                                    [user.email]) #Destinatario

    message.attach_alternative(content, 'text/html')
    message.send()
```

Debemos importar la clase *EmailMultiAlternatives* y el módulo *settings*.

Lo primero que debemos hacer es generar nuestro mensaje, para ello nos apoyamos de *EmailMultiAlternatives*. Definimos el subject, el remitente y finalmente los destinatarios(Esto último mediante una lista).

El siguiente paso es agregar un cuerpo al mensaje. Para ello me apoyo de un template renderizado.

y finalmente, con el método send enviamos el correo.

El llamado de la función pudiera ser la siguiente.

```
user = User.objects.last()

send_user_mail(user)
```

Comment: Hola Carlos espero que estes muy bien mira intente coloque las variables de entorno tal cual comentaste cree un nuevo file para incluir la funcion que me renderizara el template y realizara el envio pero no se establecio asi no se si me podrias brindar otro punto de vista